# Is there a standard that defines what is a valid SSID and password?

Tags: wifi, ssid

We are developing a wireless n/w configuration UI and need to check if a SSID is a valid one? 
Are there any restrictions on the character set? length ? anything more..

Answer (score 69):

Section 7.3.2.1 of the 802.11-2007 specification (http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2007.pdf) defines SSIDs.

A valid SSID is 0-32 octets with arbitrary contents. A 0-length SSID indicates the wildcard SSID (in probe request frames for instance).

There's no character set associated with the SSID - a 32-byte string of NUL-bytes is a valid SSID.

This implies:

- you should never use normal string functions when manipulating generic SSIDs (strcpy() and friends).
- you should not assume that the SSID is printable when, for instance, logging it to disk

Comment: There's updated version of standard ( http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2012.pdf ), which defines `SSIDEncoding` field. It can be `UNSPECIFIED` ( for arbitrary data ) or `UTF8`.

Comment: It can contain any UTF-8 characters?

Comment: It can contain any type of data.

Comment: Post should be updated with the new standard information

Comment: The link from @AndreyStarodubtsev is dead for me, so I found this one instead: http://www.academia.edu/6564159/Part_11_Wireless_LAN_Medium_Access_Control_MAC_and_Physical_Layer_PHY_Specifications_Sponsored_by_the_LAN_MAN_Standards_Committee

Comment: Sadly the link from @SámalRasmussen is also dead

Comment: The internet is trying hard to forget it seems. Found the 2016 standard here: https://www.candelatech.com/downloads/802.11-2016.pdf
page 790 section 9.4.2.2 has the definition.

Comment: Looks like that file is in the wayback machine, so it should be harder to lose this time: https://web.archive.org/web/20220609113903/https://www.candelatech.com/downloads/802.11-2016.pdf

Answer (score 17):

According to last standard 802.11-2012 (Section 6.3.11.2.2), it can be 0-32 octets with an unspecified or UTF8 encoding.

Comment: Microsoft -- as usual -- messed it: While Windows Phone 8 displayed it correctly UTF8 decoded, Windows 10 Mobile now decodes it using Windows-1252 or Latin1.