# Regex pattern to capture value in a key-par inside double quotes

Tags: regex

I want to capture `BBKH2-0272-2` , `BBH@5` , `1234` in the below string (capture value where key is **ssidname** or **SSIDName**).

```
{"SSIDIndex":2,"SSIDName":"BBKH2-0272-2" ,"Band":"2.4GHz","Status":"RadioIndex":1,"SSIDIndex":3,"SSIDName":"BBH@5","ssidname":"1234", "ssid_name":"MKLM-098", ssidname=ppoin }
```

I am using this regex :

> (?<=(?i)("SSIDName":"))(\w{1,8})

but it's not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need look behind, and can use this regex and capture group 1,

```
(?i)"SSIDName":"([^"]+)"
```

Basically you want to capture all the values of key attribute `SSIDName` and case insensitive as one of your keys is in lowercase.

**[Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Kb5z5H/1)**

Your regex, `(?<=(?i)("SSIDName":"))(\w{1,8})` is fine but will obstruct while capturing `BBH@5` as you are trying to capture it with `\w` and `@` is not part of `\w`. If you change your regex to this,

```
(?<=(?i)(?:"SSIDName":"))([\w@-]+)
```

Then even your regex can capture what you need.

**[Demo for your modified regex](https://regex101.com/r/Kb5z5H/3)**

But in general, you should try and keep your regex to be simple and avoid look arounds as not all languages and tools support look arounds, and your regex can work for most languages/tools.

Comment: You should add `-` in your second regex otherwise it will not select the name completely if there is a `-` in it. Also note that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4919889/is-there-a-standard-that-defines-what-is-a-valid-ssid-and-password SSIDName can accept any characters so your `[^"]` is a better solution anyway +1!

Comment: @Allan: Yes Alan you are right. `-` will also be needed. But best is to use my solution which doesn't use look arounds at all and captures any text contained within doublequotes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for regex and explanation @pushpesh . It's working .

Comment: Glad to help Mohit :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the following non-greedy approach:

`(?i)(?:"ssidname":")(.*?)"`

All I am doing is looking for the string `"ssidname":"` and capturing the value (without quotes) until the end quote is encountered.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kgWeBD/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one too.

```
 (?<=(?i)("SSIDName":"))([a-zA-z0-9-@]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you have been using such difficult regex

this can be done by using

regex : /^"SSIDName":"(.*?)"/gmi

g - checks globally ie. don't return after the first match.

m - matches from start to end of line ie. multiline.

i - case-insensitive match.

Check [Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/Wo9zBU/1).

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following regex (very close to yours):

```
(?i)(?<="SSIDName":")[^"]+(?=")
```

with the string:

```
{"SSIDIndex":2,"SSIDName":"BBKH2-0272-2" ,"Band":"2.4GHz","Status":"RadioIndex":1,"SSIDIndex":3,"SSIDName":"BBH@5","ssidname":"1234" }
```

It will only select:

```
BBKH2-0272-2
BBH@5
1234
```

As shown in https://regex101.com/r/3Teuiq/1/