# C# to VB.NET conversion of list sort

Tags: c#, vb.net

For C# people easy question, VB.NET syntax equivalent of:

```
wlanBssEntries.Sort(delegate ( Wlan.WlanBssEntry a, Wlan.WlanBssEntry b ) {
                            return sortModifier * string.Compare(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(a.dot11Ssid.SSID),
                                ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(b.dot11Ssid.SSID), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                        });
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Aside: SSIDs are [UTF-8, not always ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28450037/634824), and [the docs for the `DOT11_SSID` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/nativewifi/dot11-ssid) explain that the SSID is *not* a null-terminated ASCII string - thus you shouldn't treat it as one.  Instead, use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(a.dot11Ssid.SSID, 0, (int) a.dot11Ssid.SSIDLength)` as seen [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39587.c-managed-wifi-api.aspx).

Comment: @Matt: my structure is defined as Public Structure Dot11Ssid
            Public SSIDLength As UInteger
            <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=32)>
            Public SSID As Byte()
        End Structure

Comment: You can find code converters if you search for C# to VB.NET. This one seems to work for your case https://codeconverter.icsharpcode.net. I recommend looking into https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Jerry - Exactly.  You need to use that `SSIDLength` property.  Don't just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

working syntax is:

```
wlanBssEntries.Sort(Function(a As wlan.WlanBssEntry, b As wlan.WlanBssEntry) sortModifier * String.Compare(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(a.dot11Ssid.SSID), ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(b.dot11Ssid.SSID), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
```

Comment: As suggested, use `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()`. If the SSID is ASCII encoded, UTF8 will read it as-is, since it maps the ASCII table 1:1 (one byte per char). If it's UTF8 encoded, `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()` will return garbage.